# Javascript regex, help me with match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

guys help me please with it. I don't know how to operate with regex, I read a lot about this, but anyway, I don't understand how it works.

**This is my problem:**
I have code like this:

```
var str = "<strong>What do you think</strong> if we could just buy this <strong>Robot</strong>"; 
str = str.match(/[<strong>][a-z\s]+[<\/strong>]/gi);
```

And after code is done, I get something like this: >What do you think<,>Robot<

But I waited for this: What do you think, Robot.

What's wrong? It drives me crazy.

**UPDATE: Thanks to all of you!!! Now, solution is found**

Comment: You may rather want `.exec` since `<strong>` shouldn't be included in the match, if you want regexps at all.

Comment: For your reading pleasure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/835805.

Comment: In regex `[]` means "any of these characters", so `[<strong>]` means "`<` or `s` or `t`, etc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel like fussing with `RegExp.exec()`, use this:

```
var matches = str.match(/<strong>.*?<\/strong>/gi);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i)
    result.push(matches[i].match(/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/i)[1]);
```

Comment: Yeah!!! Finally... Wow. It works. I'm really happy now. Thanks a lot. Could you explain this logic step by step, please? I'll be appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. The first, non-greedy, matcher extracts all the `<strong>..</strong>` tags (the `?` helps avoid greedy matching: `<strong>..</strong>..<strong>...</strong>` - this string matches `/<strong>.*<\/strong>/` that was suggested in another answer. The `g` (global) flag gives you all matches in an array (an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Example:_Using_global_and_ignore_case_flags_with_match)). Now you just have to extract the `<strong>` tag contents in a loop using greedy matching, like other answers suggested.

Comment: It's awesome. With your help I made a little step in Javascript's regex.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex expression [updated]

```
(<strong>(.*?)</strong>)*
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but anyway, I've got : <strong>Robot</strong> instead: Robot. Or I can't rid of these tags?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've constantly get the same thing, plus now I've get a lot of commas (from the text that I have)

Answer (score 0):

This is how its done in most (modern) regex dialects

```
.*?(?<=<strong>)(.*?)(?=</strong>).*?|.*
```

replace with

```
$1
```

Unfortunately, Javascript does not support lookbehind. If you are up for it you can read http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript and give it a go. Pity js doesn't support such a powerful technique

Comment: That's not quite what he wanted.  He just wants the text between the `<strong></strong>` tags.

Comment: Yes, Rocket is right, I just want the text between that tags. And when I use replace - it doesn't work, I don't know why, before I post my question here, I've alredy tryied to use replace for result, but something wrong with it. Just because, I don't get the result, after I use "replace"